# Unable to install heroku toolbelt on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux

Unable to install heroku toolbelt on AWS EC2 instance.

I am trying to use mac CLI and install heroku toolbelt on an EC2 AWS ubuntu instance. I am using the command : wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh . I do not get any errors but when I type 'which heroku', it does not show that heroku is installed.